# Scrapy error when run with Celery and Django Channels is installed: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: django, scrapy, celery, python-multiprocessing, django-channels

When I run this script with Django shell it will run without error, but when I run with celery worker it get this error: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor. If I remove channels from INSTALLED_APPS the problem will be solved and task runs with celery worker without error. Running the same script with python Process (due to ReactorNotRestartable exception) in django shell get the same error which celery worker had: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor.
I think there's a conflict between Django Channels & Scrapy when spider is executed in another process.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def run_spider(spider)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
    crawler_process.crawl(spider)
    crawler_process.start()
```

exception stack trace when run with celery worker:

```
Task run spider raised unexpected: OSError(9, 'Bad file descriptor')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 256, in _add_reader
    key = self._selector.get_key(fd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/selectors.py", line 192, in get_key
    raise KeyError("{!r} is not registered".format(fileobj)) from None
KeyError: '9 is not registered'
```

exception stack trace when run with python Process in Django shell:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py in apply(self, func, args, kwds)
   1387         '''
   1388         if self._state == RUN:
-> 1389             return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
   1390
   1391     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
   1787             return self._value
   1788         else:
-> 1789             raise self._value.exception
   1790
   1791     def safe_apply_callback(self, fun, *args, **kwargs):

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```